# Android: when to delete a file after attachment to email app?

Tags: android

My app creates a file in temporary storage and writes some data to it.

```
exportFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

Then allow the user to choose an email program to attach and send the file.

I start an activity for result.

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send eMail..."), SEND_EMAIL_ACTIVITY);
```

In the onActivityResult() event I was deleting the file.

```
exportFile.delete();
```

But due to timing, I guess, sometimes the file gets attached and sent and sometimes it does not get attached, and the email arrives without the attachment.

If I remove the delete() from the onActivityResult(), then the attachment always arrives.

Question: when/how should I go about deleting this temp file so that it doesn't affect the delivery of the email?

Here is how I built my email Intent:

```
    // Send email with attachment
    String to[] = {emailAddressEditText.getText().toString()};
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "Birder's Diary Mobile: " + submitLocation.getText().toString());
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody.toString());
    Uri path = null;
    try {
        path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", exportFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sightingsCursor.close();
        return;
    }
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    // Let user pick client
    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send eMail..."),
                SEND_EMAIL_ACTIVITY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sightingsCursor.close();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: How did you build your `emailIntent`?

Comment: I have added this code to my post. Thx

Comment: Which email client are you using for testing?

Comment: I have been testing with a virtual device and the GMail app.